# Any known javascript/php dictionaries like 'word1', 'word2'?

Tags: php, javascript, dictionary, levenshtein-distance

Just recently I was looking up about [Levenshtein algorithm](http://www.jslab.dk/articles/crude.google.like.did.you.mean.in.javascript) and after searching for an hour I couldn't find a javascript file like:

```
var dictionary =
    [
      'coke',
      'cokeman',
      'cokeney'
      ]
```

Is there a faster way to do this? I haven't found any files like this and I've heard this function is kind of slow. If I could how could I do this with php?

Comment: PHP has functions for this, but do you want a dictionary of words or an implementation in PHP?

Comment: what exactly are you seeking?  A JavaScript file with an Array of English dictionary words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get that javascript file you could run `cat /usr/share/dict/words | sed "s/^.*$/\'&\'\,/g"`

replacing `/usr/share/dict/words` with a newline separated wordfile. Then all you have to do is add `var dictionary = [` and `]` maybe throwing in a semicolon at the end if you feel like it.